# How to refresh gridview after every insert command automatically?

Tags: asp.net

I am inserting data to database when i click submit button data inserted into Database but no changes get reflected in GridView without refreshing the page.
I used DataBind() also.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409339/refresh-gridview-after-adding-or-deleting-new-record-in-c-sharp

Comment: You should show some code when you ask questions like this. It would be a lot easier to help with an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Procedure which populates the GridView and then call that Procedure OnClick Event.

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 2):

it is enough to add

```
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

in your button onclick event.... no need to bind it also in Page_Load

Do you have any updatepanels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code - based on `DataBind` two times

Nota : you add this DataBind no just in your Page_Load but also in your delegate of click

```
//Your Insert in your delegate
....
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the gridviews data source through whatever means your using, for instance an sql query and then set the datasource to this and then use Gridview1.DataBind();

```
public void GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString;
            String sql = "Your Query";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then just use GetData() before you bind the gridview (possibly in your page load event).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do in your rowCommand:

```
gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e){
    gridView.EditIndex = -1; // to cancel edit mode
}
```